# How to get Comminication calls id of an online meeting?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to develop a module where I create a event from graph api to set a online meeting and then I want attendance report with time in and time out. I see Communication.Calls can do this so any way to get call Id?

Comment: You can get call id of an online meeting by calling [Get online meeting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Try if that helps.

Comment: not working for meeting generated from the same api

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT is the meetingId returned by the api `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings` equivalent to the callId ?